# Load Remote Image, then Convert to Base64 String Client Side for Caching

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-mobile, base64, local-storage

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Load an image from a remote server
2. Save the image's base64 data to localStorage
3. On the next request, if the localStorage item exists, load the image from localStorage data

This is in an attempt to strive for the fewest number of API calls - the image is a dynamically generated QR code via API call, so converting into a Base64 string before deployment is not an option here.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the browser do that for you already?

Comment: If it does, mind sharing how I can access that string to save into a variable?  I'm playing around in Chrome's Developer Tools and I'm not seeing anything to this end.

Comment: The browser has natural caching. When it requests for a resource, it checks the cache for that resource. If the resource is not yet expired, it uses it instead of requesting from the server.

Comment: I tried to achieve this with .toDataString(), however this just gives me a string that when read back into a canvas, does not produce the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to have a bit more control over caching (besides setting expiry settings on the server), have a look on how to use HTML5's [ApplicationCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). Here's a [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps) for supported browsers.

Comment: ApplicationCache almost works for me - it would be perfect if I could update the manifest after the page loads.  The problem is I don't know the image to be cached beforehand.  The user dictates via input the dynamically generated QR code.  Once it has been called the first time, I don't want every subsequent call to hit the API, only when the information that dynamically generates the image changes.

Comment: @MikeZ it would be better to add this explanation to your post. That way, others would not suggest broad solutions like mine.

Comment: I updated my question to better reflect what I'm trying to accomplish.